# Understanding liftM2 in haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I'm having a hard time understanding how `liftM2` works in haskell.
I wrote the following code but it doesn't output anything.

```
import Control.Monad
main = liftM2 (\a b -> putStrLn$show$(+) a b) readLn readLn
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the compiler can parse this without spaces around `$` . Then, here main would have type  IO (IO ())

If you want to sum "inside" IO, you can use `liftM2 (+)`, then print the result.

For example :

```
main :: IO ()
main = print =<< liftM2 (+) readLn readLn
```

Or using do notation :

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  s <- liftM2 (+) readLn readLn
  print s
```

Comment: Okay, so how would we use `liftM2` to read two integers and print their sum?

Comment: `$` without spaces is only a problem when `-XTemplateHaskell` is active. But yeah, it's probably a good idea to always put space around it, this way you won't have to worry about it in case you do need to use TH later. `$` is a very “spacey” operator anyway, what with its low precedence.

Answer (score 13):

It helps to start with the type of `liftM2`:

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
```

The first argument is a function of 2 arguments, like `(+)`. Normally, you would use `(+)` like this:

```
> 3 + 5
8
```

However, you don't have two values of type `Num a => a`; you are using `readLn :: Read a => IO a` to get values of type `Num a => IO a`. If you try to add those values directly:

```
:t (+) readLn readLn
(+) readLn readLn :: (Read a, Num (IO a)) => IO a
```

It requires `IO a` to have a `Num` instance. That is, you don't want to add the return values of `readLn`; you want to add the numbers *wrapped* in those return values. You could do that explicitly:

```
do
 x <- readLn
 y <- readLn
 return $ x + y
```

or, you can "modify" `(+)` to unwrap the arguments implicitly, then wrap the result. That's what `liftM2` does: it takes a 2-argument function, and "lifts" it into the monad so it can work on wrapped values.

```
> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
> :t liftM2 (+)
liftM2 (+) :: (Num r, Monad m) => m r -> m r -> m r
```

So while `(+) 3 5 :: Num a => a`, `liftM2 (+) $ (return 3) (return 5) :: (Monad m, Num a) => m a`. The former evaluates to `8`, the later, `return 8` (for whatever `return` does for the particular monad). Some non-`IO` examples:

```
> (liftM2 (+)) (Just 3) (Just 5)
Just 8
> (liftM2 (+)) [3] [5]
[8]
> (liftM2 (+)) (Right 3) (Right 5)
Right 8
```

`liftM2` is very similar to `map`; in fact, `liftM` (the version that lifts 1-argument functions) is simply another name for `map`.

Comment: while I think I can understand what you want to explain, I think your line `liftM2 (+) $ (IO 3) (IO 5) == IO 8` could be quite misleading.

Comment: What, just because `IO 3` and `IO 5` aren't actually valid Haskell expressions? :)

Comment: I think my change is an improvement.